# Better terms for "Investigative Abilities" and "General Abilities"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, synonyms

I'm writing a roleplaying game based on the Gumshoe system (I swear this is a language question rather than one for rpg.stackexhange.com!).

Characters in this games have a set of Investigative Abilities and a set of General Abilities.

The two sets of abilities function in very different ways and have very different purposes, and in playing the game previously, there was some confusion because they're both described as "abilities" despite featuring different rules.

Investigative Abilities are things like forensic science, evidence collection, research - things that allow the characters in the game to find clues. They *always* succeed.

General Abilities are things like driving, fighting, pick-pocketing - things that don't in and of themselves lead to clues, and that also *might* fail.

Is there a better way of describing these two sets of abilities that more clearly delineates them?

Comment: How about "Investigative Skills" and "General Abilities"?

Comment: I would rather call all of them Skills, and have Skill Categories, and the Categories can be named Investigation, General.

Comment: I'd incline to [***competencies***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competence) for the first set *(ability to do something **successfully** or efficiently)*. [This guy](http://www.resultpal.com/difference-skills-competencies/) is effectively making the case for the second set being ***skills***, but I think plain ***abilities*** might be more intuitively distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Street and University

Some skills can be learned on the street and some skills can be learned in a university. Both are useful. One is basic and one is informed.

Comment: This sounds appropriately hard-boiled.

Answer (score 0):

Cognitive abilities vs. physical capabilities?